# How we can get the Element from Set in Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, set

This is my object `FTContent`

```
class FTContent: NSManagedObject { 
    @NSManaged var content_id: String // Primary key
    @NSManaged var title: String
}
```

in my class i have an Set which hold `FTContent` element

```
var mySet: Set<FTContent>
```

After some operation `mySet` contains 5 element of `FTContent`

Now i want element(`FTContent`) from  `mySet` 
How can get the Element from Set?

Comment: @MartinR : in the link below, Set in swift is said to be `unordered collection`. https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/set. But it seem that we can get an element at a Index from a Set, or get the Index of an element in the Set.

Comment: @Hoa: Up to Swift 2, Set was documented as *"A collection of unique Element instances with no defined ordering."*, see e.g. http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Set/. I think that describes it better. As a collection, it has an index and a subscript method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `Set` is a `Collection` and you can simply iterate over its elements:

```
for elem in mySet {
    print(elem)
}
```

or access by subscripting:

```
for idx in mySet.indices {
    let elem = mySet[idx]
    print(elem)
}
```

But note that the order of elements in a set is unspecified 
(and can change if elements are inserted or deleted).
So you might want to *sort* it into an *array,* for example:

```
// Swift 2.2:
let allElements = mySet.sort({ $0.content_id < $1.content_id })

// Swift 3:
let allElements = mySet.sorted(by: { $0.content_id < $1.content_id } )
```

Comment: Thanks Martin it will help a lot. ;)

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
mySet[advance(mySet.startIndex, 2)] // check index("2")
```

Comment: Just do `Array(mySet)[2]`